# Short story where the stars are eyes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short story I read several years ago in either Analog or Asimov's Science Fiction, probably between 2011 and 2013.

In the story there's a 4th spatial dimension whose axes are skew, so that things get closer together the higher up you go in the 4th dimension. Spaceships travel faster by making jumps up in that dimension, during which all viewports are blocked, then jumping back down to our universe for navigation. The narrator is on a ship coming back from asteroid mining in I think the Kuiper Belt, but the jumps start going wrong - the ship is jumping further up than down and starts drifting higher up in the 4th dimension - and this causes strange happenings onboard. People start disappearing during jumps. Eventually the engineer forces the viewports to remain open during jumps, and the narrator notices that the stars start appearing bigger and closer together. They go from being point light sources to tendrilled orbs in the distance, almost like an old drawing of the sun, and eventually as the ship gets high enough and the universe gets skew enough, the stars *open* - they become huge eyes staring at the ship from space - and the ship keeps wandering aimlessly.

The framing device is people telling horror stories around a campfire, during which the narrator mysteriously appears, tells this story, then vanishes. I think the people at the campfire talk after about how the story reminds them of news reports of disappeared mining ships but I'm not sure